# _delay_us(); timing explanation

Tags: c, embedded

I made a program with atmega16 and was trying to make my own `delay_us()` so I looked into the compiler avr-gcc library for `_delay_us()` function and this is its code:

```
static inline void _delay_us(double __us) __attribute__((always_inline));

/*
\ingroup util_delay
Perform a delay of \c __us microseconds, using _delay_loop_1().

The macro F_CPU is supposed to be defined to a
constant defining the CPU clock frequency (in Hertz).

The maximal possible delay is 768 us / F_CPU in MHz.

If the user requests a delay greater than the maximal possible one,
_delay_us() will automatically call _delay_ms() instead.  The user
will not be informed about this case.
*/
 void
 _delay_us(double __us)
 {
 uint8_t __ticks;
double __tmp = ((F_CPU) / 3e6) * __us; //number of ticks per us * delay time in us
if (__tmp < 1.0)
    __ticks = 1;
else if (__tmp > 255)
{
    _delay_ms(__us / 1000.0);
    return;
}
else
    __ticks = (uint8_t)__tmp;
_delay_loop_1(__ticks); // function decrements ticks untill it reaches 0( takes 3 cycles)
}
```

I got confused about how, if I use a 1Mhz clock, this function that contains floating point arithmetic will be able to make small delays (like `_delay_us(10)`), because executing all the the setup code will definitely take more time than that. So I wrote this program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define F_CPU 1000000UL

int main()
{
     _delay_ms(1000);
    DDRB=0XFF;
    PORTB=0XFF;
    _delay_us(10);
    PORTB=0;

    for(;;){}
    return 0;
}
```

I simulated it using protues and used an oscilloscope and connected one of PORTB pins to its input. Then I saw that the delay was exactly 10 us. How could the delay be that accurate considering this set up code statement that uses floating point arithmetic:

```
    double __tmp = ((F_CPU) / 4e3) * __ms;
```

This should have taken a lot of cycles that makes `_delay_us(10)` exceed the 10 us period, but the time was exactly 10us!!

Comment: the float should cause lots of problems yes, very bad implementation.  did you look at the output of the compiler it may have done all the math at compile time and left some very calls/loops behind.

Comment: That is a truly terrible implementation;  it might be adequate for constant delays, but for variable delays it will code bloat and unpredictable.  It has to be calibrated.  Even the comment _"The maximal possible delay is 768 us / F_CPU in MHz."_ makes no sense - that is a _very_ small maximum!  If you want accurate timing use a hardware timer and for small delays poll its counter, for larger delays count its interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

All the floating point arithmetic is calculated by the preprocessor as these delay functions are actually macros. So at the point the mcu executes the code, all that's left is a loop that uses an integer to do the delay.

Comment: they are inline functions as you see from their declarations and are put in the delay.h but I don't think that is the floating point is calculated at the preprocessor stage as the value of __ms changes every time we call this function so it must be in the compiling stage

Comment: @AliMak The value of `__us` doesn't change in the example you used to time it, it's fixed at 10. What happens if you define `volatile double delay = 10.0;` then call `_delay_us(delay);` instead of `_delay_us(10);`?

Comment: so the what you mean is that the compiler makes these calculations at compile time and then put the results directly in the loop function?

Comment: @D Krueger usually with delay macros using variables produces an error, you need to use constants.

Comment: @Ali Mak, that's exactly right. You can do a simple test. Make some code that uses floating point variables. Then add the floating point code to your delay code. Does the output code size change by a lot? Usually the floating point libraries that are included are quite large, especially on 8 bit mcus which usually don't support floating point in hardware.

Comment: make a loop with an integer that counts from 1 to 100, feed that counter into the delay function, forcing it to compute it runtime, examine the disassembly.  compare that to putting a hardcoded value like 10 in the code, you should see the compile time optimizations we are talking about.

Comment: inline nor macros have anything to do with runtime vs compile time, the compiler doesnt see that that is all expanded into one huge file before the compiler is called.  It is whether or not the compiler can optimize at compile time or not.

Comment: @imqqmi I made a program which has this double  x=5000.2/100.442;  PORTB=x;  and then I looked into the assembly of the program found that the complier puts directly 49 in PORTB .It worked as I understood in my last comment , the compiler calculates the value of x in  compile time and puts the result directly in PORTB so no floating point arithmetic  needed at run time. But I must activate the compiler optimization otherwise everything is done at run time including the floating point calculations and libraries

Comment: @imqqmi It's not a macro, it's an inline function.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
#define F_CPU 16000000

extern void _delay_loop_1( uint8_t );

static void _delay_us(double __us)
{
    uint8_t __ticks;

    double __tmp = ((F_CPU) / 3e6) * __us; 
    if (__tmp < 1.0)
    {
        __ticks = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (__tmp > 255)
        {
            _delay_ms(__us / 1000.0);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            __ticks = (uint8_t)__tmp;
        }
    }
    _delay_loop_1(__ticks); 
}


void fun1 ( void )
{
    _delay_us(10);
}
```

which with gcc can produce this:

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   85 e3           ldi r24, 0x35   ; 53
   2:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0x4 <__zero_reg__+0x3>
```

the number to feed _delay_loop_1 is computed at compile time not runtime, all of that dead code goes away.

but add this:

```
void fun2 ( void )
{
    uint8_t ra;
    for(ra=1;ra<10;ra++) _delay_us(ra);
}
```

and things change dramatically.

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   85 e3           ldi r24, 0x35   ; 53
   2:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0x4 <fun2>

00000004 <fun2>:
   4:   8f 92           push    r8
   6:   9f 92           push    r9
   8:   af 92           push    r10
   a:   bf 92           push    r11
   c:   cf 92           push    r12
   e:   df 92           push    r13
  10:   ef 92           push    r14
  12:   ff 92           push    r15
  14:   cf 93           push    r28
  16:   c1 e0           ldi r28, 0x01   ; 1
  18:   6c 2f           mov r22, r28
  1a:   70 e0           ldi r23, 0x00   ; 0
  1c:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  1e:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  20:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x22 <fun2+0x1e>
  22:   86 2e           mov r8, r22
  24:   97 2e           mov r9, r23
  26:   a8 2e           mov r10, r24
  28:   b9 2e           mov r11, r25
  2a:   2b ea           ldi r18, 0xAB   ; 171
  2c:   3a ea           ldi r19, 0xAA   ; 170
  2e:   4a ea           ldi r20, 0xAA   ; 170
  30:   50 e4           ldi r21, 0x40   ; 64
  32:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x34 <fun2+0x30>
  34:   c6 2e           mov r12, r22
  36:   d7 2e           mov r13, r23
  38:   e8 2e           mov r14, r24
  3a:   f9 2e           mov r15, r25
  3c:   20 e0           ldi r18, 0x00   ; 0
  3e:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
  40:   40 e8           ldi r20, 0x80   ; 128
  42:   5f e3           ldi r21, 0x3F   ; 63
  44:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x46 <fun2+0x42>
  46:   87 fd           sbrc    r24, 7
  48:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0x4a <fun2+0x46>
  4a:   20 e0           ldi r18, 0x00   ; 0
  4c:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
  4e:   4f e7           ldi r20, 0x7F   ; 127
  50:   53 e4           ldi r21, 0x43   ; 67
  52:   9f 2d           mov r25, r15
  54:   8e 2d           mov r24, r14
  56:   7d 2d           mov r23, r13
  58:   6c 2d           mov r22, r12
  5a:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x5c <fun2+0x58>
  5c:   18 16           cp  r1, r24
  5e:   04 f0           brlt    .+0         ; 0x60 <fun2+0x5c>
  60:   9f 2d           mov r25, r15
  62:   8e 2d           mov r24, r14
  64:   7d 2d           mov r23, r13
  66:   6c 2d           mov r22, r12
  68:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x6a <fun2+0x66>
  6a:   86 2f           mov r24, r22
  6c:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x6e <fun2+0x6a>
  6e:   cf 5f           subi    r28, 0xFF   ; 255
  70:   ca 30           cpi r28, 0x0A   ; 10
  72:   01 f4           brne    .+0         ; 0x74 <fun2+0x70>
  74:   cf 91           pop r28
  76:   ff 90           pop r15
  78:   ef 90           pop r14
  7a:   df 90           pop r13
  7c:   cf 90           pop r12
  7e:   bf 90           pop r11
  80:   af 90           pop r10
  82:   9f 90           pop r9
  84:   8f 90           pop r8
  86:   08 95           ret
  88:   20 e0           ldi r18, 0x00   ; 0
  8a:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
  8c:   4a e7           ldi r20, 0x7A   ; 122
  8e:   54 e4           ldi r21, 0x44   ; 68
  90:   9b 2d           mov r25, r11
  92:   8a 2d           mov r24, r10
  94:   79 2d           mov r23, r9
  96:   68 2d           mov r22, r8
  98:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x9a <fun2+0x96>
  9a:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x9c <fun2+0x98>
  9c:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0x9e <fun2+0x9a>
  9e:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
  a0:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0xa2 <__SREG__+0x63>
```

hmm, how good is the optimizer?

```
void fun3 ( void )
{
    uint8_t ra;
    for(ra=20;ra<22;ra++) _delay_us(ra);
}
```

thought so

```
00000004 <fun3>:
   4:   8a e6           ldi r24, 0x6A   ; 106
   6:   00 d0           rcall   .+0         ; 0x8 <fun3+0x4>
   8:   80 e7           ldi r24, 0x70   ; 112
   a:   00 c0           rjmp    .+0         ; 0xc <fun3+0x8>
```

figured the count to 10 would have done it.

A lot of times you will see delay loop functions like this get used with hardcoded values because the spec for whatever you are bit banging, etc has those values and it is easy when the thing says pop reset then wait 100us, you just call a delay with 100 in it.  Now if there is one file with:

```
fun4(10);
```

and another file (another optimization domain) you have the above with this added:

```
void fun4 ( uint8_t x)
{
    _delay_us(x);
}
```

you can then understand where this is headed...runtime...dont even need to compile it to see that it will have the problem.  Now some compilers like llvm you can optimize across file domains, but they dont target the AVR, their MSP430 was a publicity stunt more than reality as it doesnt work and is not supported.  Their arm support is obviously good, but they change their command line options pretty much every minor release, I have long since gotten tired trying to use them as I have to constantly change my makefiles to keep up, and their optimized code is sadly as not as fast as gccs despite gccs code getting worse every release and llvm getting a little better (worse/better are in the eyes of the beholder of course).

Comment: BTW this is just imqqmi's answer explained...so upvote that answer...(although macros and inlines have zero to do with it)